# Mysql list in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to replace the current baseUrl list in the code below, with my 'url' list that is in a mysql database.

I have tried to work with something like 'echo json_encode($url)' but I can't figure it out.

How can I get my 'url' list that's in my mysql database into the script below at the baseUrl position?

Any help and pointers in the right direction are really appreciated.

```
<script>  
var baseUrl = '/';

var mySwipe = $('#pageBody').responsiveSwipe({
    edition: [
        baseUrl,
        baseUrl + '1.php',
        baseUrl + '2.php',
        baseUrl + '3.php',

    ],
    widthGuess: 0,
    emulator: window.location.hash.match(/emulator/)
});

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('click', '.next', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        mySwipe.gotoNext();
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.prev', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        mySwipe.gotoPrev();
    });

})

</script>
```

Comment: make an ajax call to a page (I assume you want to use PHP based on your question) that queries the DB and returns the value that you want...?  or, if you already have the value on the page, do the echo like this (assuming php again): `var url = '<?php echo $url ?>';`